# Error: no known conversion for argument 4 from 'const ServerLogInfo' to 'ServerLogInfo&'

Tags: c++, lambda, func, ref

```
int AsyncParseInternal(const std::string& data, DictEntry* entries, int num_dense, ServerLogInfo& serverlog, time_t timestamp)
{
    auto func = [this, data, entries, num_dense, serverlog, timestamp]() {
        this->ParseInternal(data, entries, num_dense, serverlog, timestamp);
    };
    util::ThreadCaller::call_method(std::move(func));
    return 0;
}

int ParseInternal(
    const std::string& data, DictEntry* entries, int num_dense, ServerLogInfo& serverlog, time_t timestamp)
{
    ...
}
```

> no known conversion for argument 4 from 'const ServerLogInfo' to 'ServerLogInfo&'

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
void f(int&) {}

struct S {
  void operator()() const { f(x); }
  int x;
};
```

This doesn't compile due to `operator()` being marked `const`. C++ lambdas are function objects with `operator()` that is implicitly marked `const`.

In order to get a non-`const` `operator()`, you need to mark the lambda `mutable`.
i.e.,

```
auto func = [...]() mutable { ... };
                    ^^^^^^^
```